# UITableView stays behind of a UIView while scrolling strange white gap

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello everyone i have been struggling the pas 8 hours to find a solution but i can't seem to find out. I have an app where i implemented the following task. When the user scrolls up the navigationbar hides and an UIView takes its place where there are two buttons on this UIView as you see in the picture. One button TableView and another Options. The problem is as you see in the picture that there is a white gap between the UIView that is on top (which actually took the place of the navigation bar) and the UITableView (you can see part of the first image in the UITableView). I do not know why this is happening. This is my code in ScrollView. Actually i want to move the UITableView exactly under the UIView that took the place of the navigation bar so there is no gap but it stays behind this white gap! Please any help or thoughts appreciated!

[image]

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  
    CGFloat scrollPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y ;

          if(scrollPos > _currentOffset ){

              //Fully hide your toolbar
              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
        
                  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
                  CGRect newRect1 = self.initialHeaderRect;
               
                  newRect1.origin.y -=self.initialHeaderRect.size.height;
                  self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = newRect1;
               }];

              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
                  
              CGRect newRect1 = self.initialHeaderRect1;
              
              newRect1.origin.y -= self.initialHeaderRect1.size.height;
                         self.segView.frame = newRect1;
             
              }];

              CGRect newRect2 = self.initialTableContainerRect;
              newRect2.origin.y -= 20;
               self.tView.frame = newRect2;
           
          } else {
            
              //Slide it up incrementally, etc.
              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{

                  CGRect newRect = self.initialHeaderRect;
                  self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = newRect;
       
                  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0f;
                  CGRect newRect1 = self.initialHeaderRect1;
                 self.segView.frame = newRect1;

                  CGRect newRect2 = self.initialTableContainerRect;
                  newRect2.origin.y += 20;
                   self.initialHeaderRect1.size.height;
                   self.tView.frame = newRect2;
              }];
          }

 
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   
    scrollView = self.tableView;
     _currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    
}
```

Comment: From the first sight, it seems to be a layout problem, not caused by scrolling. How do you position the table view? I think your constraints should ensure that initially table view's top is pinned to the bottom of the navigation bar and then moved up until it reaches your tabs view.

Comment: Everything is done through code. It's not my project just trying to figure out how to hide the navigation bar on scrolling of uitableview...